# How to update value of a firestore document with a firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have firestore database and I would like to trigger a cloud functions when there is a change in a field of a firestore document. I would like the cloud function to look at what has changed and use the new data to update another filed of the firestore document.

Example

Lets assume the document in the picture has changed and has the new values as in the picture below

[image]

Now I would like to update the value of `accuracy` to `successes / attempts`, ie I would like accuracy to be 6/11 = 0.54

What should I write in the function? Here is what I have so far

```
exports.calculateAccuracy = functions.firestore.document('/users/{userId}/wordScores')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {

      //what to write here?

    });
```

Extra question: how many reads/writes I am going to consume to update the accuracy?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do the trick. Notice the path in the Cloud Firestore trigger (`users/{userId}/wordScores/{scoreDocId}`): it points to a Document, not to a Collection. More info in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events).

```
exports.calculateAccuracy = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}/wordScores/{scoreDocId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {

        const newValue = change.after.data();
        const previousValue = change.before.data();

        if ((newValue.attempts !== previousValue.attempts) || (newValue.successes !== previousValue.successes)) {
            return change.after.ref.update({
                accuracy: newValue.successes / newValue.attempts
            });

        } else {
            return null;
        }

    });
```

Comment: Many thanks! Do you know how many reads and writes I am invoking using this function?

Comment: You will pay for the update of the Firestore document. But also for the Function invocation, etc. See the following docs/articles for more info on pricing: https://firebase.google.com/pricing, https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-functions-tutorial-pricing-9cc6dc47f7c0, https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing